# how to add the price to a paypal email link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal

I have created a paypal link using Paypal create button. I don't need the button I just need the link to be sent in an email.

The amount the user has to pay is determined on my website so I can't put the price.

How can I add it to the link in the email so when the user clicks the link and goes to paypal the amount to pay appears.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I did it as follows:

```
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=[enter the email address of paypal account]&currency_code=USD&item_name=[enter your items name]&amount=[enter the price]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create one link,add onclick event which call javascript function, the function submits paypal form,